# Problemas con Bcrypt Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, hash

Estoy intentando hacer una interface de cambio de contraseña en mi pagina, pero tengo un problema con los hash `bcrypt`

```
$userMatch = DB::table('users')
    ->where('id','=',$userID)
    ->where('password','=',bcrypt($request->password))
    ->count();
```

El problema es que al hacer la comparación para ver si es que hay algún usuario con que tenga el ID y que tenga la misma contraseña me sale que no son iguales.

La contraseña es 1234 (Esta esta guardada como brcypt dentro de la base de datos)
Ingreso por formulario 1234, lo convierto con bcrypt() para hacer la comparacion, pero sigue diciendome que no son iguales.

Comment: Eso es para hacerlo mediante `Hash::make` (Si no me equivoco) pero yo encripte mis datos con `bcrypt( )`

Comment: Normalmente bcrypt genera un hash, que cambia cada ocasión, por lo que la constraseña no sera igual. aqui unas ligas de referencia.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#verifying-that-a-password-matches-a-hash
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Comparto algo parecido a lo que indica @HammerffallBK https://stackoverflow.com/a/35716183

Comment: Idiota de mi, tenia el nombre de la variable en minuscula.